# GDI and DirectX coexistence and priority

Tags: windows, winapi, directx, gdi

I was wondering, how do these two coexist as different controllers of the same windows UI, and which is processed first?

To write DirectX code you do not need to remove any of the Win32Api code, which may as well contain GDI code, and nothing stops you from calling GDI and Win32 functions. In fact, nothing is even touched when interpreting the WM_PAINT message. So how do they operate on the same surface? Will DirectX render what it has to render and then the GDI rendering will get on top, or the other way around, or is it random?

Comment: In modern Windows (Windows 7+), GDI and DirectX are actually layered on top of the same lower-level system. Windows calls this "DirectX Graphics Infrastructure" (DXGI) even though it's basically what every hardware accelerated graphics API on the system (including OpenGL) uses for drawing. In any event, they should interoperate with no problems in all versions of Windows - GDI's just not hardware accelerated in Windows Vista.

Comment: Well, good to know they run without conflict, but any clue as to what will be rendered first and what on top? If the GDI gets on top I'd like to use it for writing some text actually, but was a good opportunity to see what else I could learn

Comment: I was not sure how to answer that part of the question, because I do not know what a UI controller is. But to render to both DirectX and GDI in the same application you can use two different HWND's and [Layered Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx). That works well for drawing on top of OpenGL contexts using GDI as well. I am not sure if _that_ is what you are looking for?

Comment: DXGI is about the adapter enumeration and screen resolution. It doesn't do anything for drawing. "Hardware accelerated GDI" uses Direct2D which itself is built on Direct3D. In some cases GDI code is actually using software to draw rasters that are then drawn as textures with Direct2D/3D.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, that could be exactly what I'm lookng for, I'll look into it

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn, I was aware of Direct2D being an intermediate step between the GDI and the final output, but as I'm handling two different functions, one for DirectX rendering, and one for GDI, it gets a bit messed up as to which comes first...

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: DXGI handles surface management, swap chain, etc. All the things necessary to actually implement rendering APIs. [Here's the proper overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I was correcting this statement: "Windows calls this "DirectX Graphics Infrastructure" (DXGI) ... what every hardware accelerated graphics API on the system (including OpenGL) uses for drawing". DXGI does not have any code for 'drawing'. Just surfaces.